# Unable to send email from button click. ASP.NET and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, web, smtp

I have little experience with C# and I am currently having an issue with sending an email from a button click to a specified address.

I have an ASP.NET webpage which contains a contact form. I want a user to enter data into text boxes and then when they click the "SEND" button this information is sent via email.

However when i click send i get the following.

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 209.85.229.109:25**

The C# code is as follows.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(txtemail.Text);
    mail.To.Add("hmgomez90@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Taxi Taxi Support";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = "First Name: " + txtname.Text;
    mail.Body += "Email: " + txtemail.Text;
    mail.Body += "Comments: " + txtquestion.Text;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

I am using the System.Net and System.Net.Mail

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551926/sending-email-through-gmail)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you'll also need to specify the port (587) and credentials in order to use Google's SMTP server.

Have a look at this question: [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c) which includes the code:

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're usage of MailMessage looks correct but I would question the SMTP settings. Gmail tends to be picky and will probably require you to define a port.

[From the Gmail Help:](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287)

smtp.gmail.com (use authentication)

Use Authentication: Yes

Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

Port for SSL: 465

So you might add

```
smtp.Port = 587
```